# SQLAlchemy + MYSQL unique string column gets truncated

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I would like to enforce the uniqueness of a column, but after I add an object to the database the string in this unique column gets cutoff. I have a model defined as follows:

```
class Topic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'topic'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    slug = Column(String(256), nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = Column(String(256))
```

Im using SQLAlchemy and MYSQL. When I inspect the table that gets created:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE topic;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| slug     | varchar(10)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

How do I get the slug column to have type varchar(256) and Key UNI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy doesn't support database migrations. For that, you'd need something like [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is authored by the same person who wrote SQLAlchemy.

Alternatively, you can issue a DDL statement directly on the MySQL server, and change the Table Definition in Python.

*[on mysql]*

```
ALTER TABLE topic MODIFY COLUMN slug VARCHAR(256);
```

*[on python]*

```
class Topic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'topic'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    slug = Column(String(256), nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = Column(String(256))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also discovered that there is a max key length of 767 bytes so String(256) will not fit. I was able to decrease the length and everything works fine.